# unable to understand code of .ftl files in struts2

Tags: struts2

I am unable to understand the code given below.Can anyone suggest me how to write the code for .ftl files  .I am following the turtorial  http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/

```
      <#--
Only show message if errors are available.
This will be done if ActionSupport is used.
   -->
   <#assign hasFieldErrors = parameters.name?? && fieldErrors?? 
        &&    fieldErrors[parameters.name]??/>
     <#if hasFieldErrors>
     <#list fieldErrors[parameters.name] as error>
    <span class="errorMessage" errorFor="${parameters.id}">${error?html}</span><#t/>
    </#list>
    </#if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts2 templates are written in Freemarker. You need to have a little Freemarker knowledge to understand the code. Here's the [manual](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/index.html) to get you started.